# has_many through help, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models are like this:

```
User
   has_and_belongs_to_many :Roles

Role
   has_and_belongs_to_many :Users
```

tables:

```
roles_users
   user_id
   role_id

roleGroups
   id
   role_id
   some_column
```

Now I want to create another association on the User model, that will be a collection of all roleGroups the user belongs to.

**i.e. if the user is in roles with id's 1 and 2, then fetch all RoleGroups where role_id = 1 and 2.**

I think I need to use a through because it is based on the user's Role association right?

I tried:

```
User
   has_many  :RoleGroups, :through => :Roles

Role
   has_many :RoleGroups, :through => :User
```

But I get an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many :RoleGroups, :through => :Roles.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.
```

**Update**
Ok my models look like this now:

```
User
   habtm :Roles
   has_many :RoleGroups, :through => :Roles

Role
  habtm :Users
  has_many :RoleGroups

RoleGroup
  belongs_to :Role
```

mysql tables:

```
roles_users
   user_id
   role_id

role_groups
   id
   role_id
   col3
   col4
   ..
```

If I do:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.Roles  (works fine)
u.RoleGroups   #see error
```

**Error message:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `role_groups`.* FROM `role_groups` INNER JOIN `roles` ON `role_groups`.role_id = `roles`.id WHERE ((`roles`.user_id = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) association.

Comment: between User + RoleGroup and Role + RoleGroup?  but the join table RoleGroups doesn't have userid...

Comment: You don't need a model for the join table with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Look at the Rails guide linked, it has diagrams showing the table layout.

Comment: Hi, your right that was a type, I fixed it.  But this still doesn't work: user.RoleGroups, I'll put the error in my question

Comment: Can a role belong to more than one role group? Does a user have many roles or role groups (it shouldn't be both, IMO)?

Comment: Yes a role can belong to 1 or more role groups, rolegroups have other FK's on it so it does make sense.  A user can have many roles, and many roleGroups (role groups is a bad name, I will change it ask it gets confusing -- it is not really a roleGroup..its more than that)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this the way you're thinking. I'm not sure why you're capitalizing your associations, but there are a few other things wrong, too.

First, `RoleGroups` hangs off of `Role` (via `has_many`, but more on that in a sec), which means you don't have a direct connection between `User` and `RoleGroup`.

Second, it appears from your updated explanation that each `RoleGroup` can have more than one `Role`, which is normal, but in your code `Role has_many :role_groups`, which means each role can have more than one role group. This is counterintuitive naming, but perhaps intentional. I'm going to assume that your role groups contain multiple roles rather than the other way around.

Third, you can't use a HABTM as a `:through` model. HABTM only uses a table in the database, not a Rails model, so the information in your `roles_users` table can't be used directly; `has_many :foos :through => :bars` requires an actual `Bar` model.

```
# Models
User
  habtm :roles

Role
  habtm :users
  belongs_to :role_group # add role.role_group_id attribute

RoleGroup
  has_many :roles # remove role_groups.role_id attribute

# Console
u = User.find(1) # get user
r = u.roles      # get user roles
u.roles.collect { |role| role.role_group.name } 
# ["Administrative","Editorial","User"]
```